# Fetching the greatest data lesser than the data in the current row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 3 columns: `Id`, `Number` and `Date`, out of which `ID` and `Number` together form a primary key. The table looks like this:

```
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | ID | Number | Date             |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 1  | 1234   | 10-12-13 1:05:33 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 1  | 2314   | 10-12-13 1:10:32 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 2  | 1234   | 10-13-14 3:04:55 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 3  | 4312   | 05-12-13 5:05:00 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 3  | 1234   | 04-13-12 3:12:53 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
    | 4  | 4312   | 05-12-11 5:05:00 |  |
    +----+--------+------------------+--+
```

Now, I want the maximum date for a number that's less than the date for each row, irrespective of the ID. So, for ID = 1 and Number = 1234, I want the date that was maximum for 1234 but less than the date it has in that row. The result should be 04-13-12 3:12:53. Similarly, for ID = 2 and Number = 1234, the result should be 10-12-13 1:05:33.

So the output should look like:

```
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | ID | Number | Date             | Prev Date        |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 1  | 1234   | 10-12-13 1:05:33 | 04-13-12 3:12:53 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 1  | 2314   | 10-12-13 1:10:32 | 10-12-13 1:10:32 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 2  | 1234   | 10-13-14 3:04:55 | 10-12-13 1:05:33 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 3  | 4312   | 05-12-13 5:05:00 | 05-12-11 5:05:00 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 3  | 1234   | 04-13-12 3:12:53 | 04-13-12 3:12:53 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
    | 4  | 4312   | 05-12-11 5:05:00 | 05-12-11 5:05:00 |
    +----+--------+------------------+------------------+
```

Hope this is clear. I am drawing a complete blank as to how I should construct my query. Thanks.

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample results in a tabular format.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added the output I need.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a cumulative max:

```
select t.*,
       max(date) over (partition by id
                       order by date
                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                      ) as prev_date
from t;
```

EDIT:

Based on the example in the question, you may want:

```
select t.*,
       max(date) over (partition by number
                       order by date
                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                      ) as prev_date
from t;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what cumulative max means? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the term

Comment: A "running max"?  It is simply the maximum value up to a particular row (or in this case, to the row before).

Comment: Should be `partition by number` to met the requirement ("_for ID = 2 and Number = 1234, the result should be 10-12-13 1:05:33_" - with your solution it will be `null`)

Comment: @Abelisto . . . The question is unclear.  I am going by:  "I want the maximum date for a number that's less than the date for each row."  I am then interpreting that this really means per id.

Comment: This looks like what I need. Let me verify the results, and I shall let you know and accept the answer. Thanks a lot!